# Xindy doesn't work: xindy.pl: input file xxx.acn doesnot exist

Tags: xindy

I want to use xindy for my glossaries. The command for calling xindy which I use is

xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo | xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.blg -o %.bls %.blo | xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn

The error is

xindy.pl: input file main.acn does not exist at c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 547.

C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:708: command failed with exit code 2: perl.exe c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M main.xdy -t main.alg -o main.acr main.acn

I update the texlive from 2015 to texlive2017, because somewhere in the web I read it may because of texlive 2015. Now, even with update texlive 2017. The same problem with exactly the same error.

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The file containing the information required by `xindy` (`main.acn`) doesn't exist, which suggests you either haven't used `\makeglossaries` or you've omitted the `acronym` package option.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, I used \makeglossaries. But I don't know   acronym package option. What is it? Thank you.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, Thank you very much. I added acronym package option to calling glossaries package and the problem solved easily. Thank again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments